# How can I use repositories in my module's build.gradle not in Top-level(Project's) build.gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

For example, when I use the 'activeandroid', I must make two paces:

1) In my Project's build.gradle(Top-level build.gradle),add

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    // ActiveAndroid
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}
```

2) In my module's build.gradle, add

```
compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

But can I add the repositories in my module's build.gradle ?
By the way, when I did that I got many errors, cannot build successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT' 
}
```

Don't confuse the `repositories` block with the repositories inside the `buildscript` block.

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me, after wrapping in the root project clause.

```
rootProject.allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make much sense since what is applied here in a subprojects build file configures others outside of it. Doing it on top level is preferable to this. Filtering for the right project could be added though to make it more appropriate.